# Spring Cloud Gateway Redis RateLimiter Example

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have an use case where I have to pre-filter a soap request by a field in that message, and add a rate limiter base on IP to that route. I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway 2.0.0.RC2.
I used readBody() method to pre-filter soap request, but I don't know how to add a rate limiter to this route

    `@Bean
    public RouteLocator wsRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, RequestRateLimiterGatewayFilterFactory rl) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/services/**")
                        .and()
                        .readBody(String.class, s -> {
                            try {
                                // Verify xml message
                            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                        .uri("http://10.60.96.56:9444")
                )
                .build();`

I found a [guide](https://youtu.be/TwVtlNX-2Hs?t=30m42s) which use Spring Cloud 2.0.0.M4. Unfortunately, I can't find readBody() method in Gateway 2.0.0.M4. 
Could somebody show me and example how to use RateLimiter in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Comment: check https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/342#issuecomment-476475591